# find out if vertices are inside or outside of another mesh, using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do you tell if verts are inside of another mesh using geometry node and store them as boolean attribute?
I tried the attribute Proximity node but it returns absolute distance to object so couldn't tell if the vertex is inside or outside the other mesh.
Assume both mesh are manifold.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(Updated.. see below)

In Blender 3.0a, there's a Ray Cast node. So you can fire a ray in an arbitrary direction from each point in the modified geometry, seeking only the target geometry. Intervening objects are ignored. 'No hit' returns 0. If-and-only-if the source vertex is inside (a manifold) target, there will be a hit-point, whose normal is  backfacing  to the ray.

[image].

**Update** for GN Fields:

[image]

[image] (Blender 3.2b)

Comment: Clever ! I have a feeling this node's going to be used in a wild range of ways :)

Comment: @Gorgious Yup! Agreed. I reckon it could often be used to wriggle out of doing tricky maths :) .. I don't know how expensive it is. If the BVH or whatever is already built, maybe not so bad.