# Using Geometry of second object for texture Fac value

Tags: texturing, materials, geometry-nodes, geometry

Hello I want to use simple mix node and I want to know if there is a way (In Eevee) to use a second object's geometry as *Fac* value (so that the one color will only be inside of the second object's volume)

[image: here i for the test i use simple cube and the plane]

To be more specific I want a way to use the second object's volume as the threshold value between 2 colors so the one color will be only visible within its volume.

[image]

Comment: I've updated [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230945/35559) to GN Fields.. it should do the job.