# Convert Position to Selection (Boolean) in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, masking

I wonder how I can convert the position output of geometry proximity node into boolean value in order to connect it to the selection input of the instance on points node. Basically I want to use the mesh as a mask to just hide every instance that are not inside of the mask, I think it is the easiest way to play with selection input of the "instance on points node"

[image]

Comment: If your test is not so much 'Position' as 'Inside/Outside' your mask, then maybe [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230945/35559)   is an approach ? (Or instance on the result of a Boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use raycast node and dot product if you want to remove you points inside the object. 
[image]