# Geo nodes: Geometry transform on collision with another object

Tags: geometry-nodes, collision

I'm trying to apply a transform to the geometry of an object when it collides with one another. Collision detection is made using Raycast. As you can see on the screenshot, there is a connection error between Greater Than and the Switch node. I don't understand why and how this can be worked around (Blender 4.0.2).

Note: the technique is based on this graph: [find out if vertices are inside or outside of another mesh, using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230921/find-out-if-vertices-are-inside-or-outside-of-another-mesh-using-geometry-nodes)

[image: Node graph showing connection error]

Comment: @StefLAncien Thanks, the logic might be flawed but what I am concerned with right now is why I have this connection error between Greater Than and Switch. When this is fixed I can rework the logic if needed. Using a Capture Attribute node doesn't help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

The [*Accumulate Field*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/field/accumulate_field.html) node is providing one value per *vertex* of the source geometry, whereas a single value per *geometry* is expected by the *Switch* node. This value can be computed by an [*Attribute Statistic*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_statistic.html) node.

[image: GN graph with attribute statistic node]

**Resources:** [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixes the problem indeed. This Attribute Statistic is the first node I see turning field into a value, somehow it seems to me more of these could be needed so we can evaluate and select specific values from fields. The Evaluate functions of fields return fields and not values.